# How can I write a MST algorithm (Prim or Kruskal) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I can write both Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms to find a minimum spanning tree in C++ or Java, but I want to know how to implement them in Haskell with O(mlogm) or O(mlogn) (pure functional programs is better). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain, what's your problem with the implementation? It's easier to help you, if we know what's your problem.

Comment: The problem is mainly about array.

Comment: Prim needs an array to record whether the node has been selected, and Kruskal needs Union Find Set. Modifying an array cost much.

Comment: @Jin Lin: You could use a tree instead of an array (for instance `Data.Set` or whatever) or some kind of mutable array. But prefer a tree.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Well, a tree's complexy is O(log(n)) and mutable array is not pure functional. Are there some other solutions? Maybe something like queue's pure functional implementation.

Comment: You can wrap a mutable array in state monad. This is very functional.

Comment: I think a tree maybe better, it wouldn't have an effect on the complexy when i use it as the flag array in prims. Thanks. :)

Comment: @FUZxxl how can a mutable array be wrapped in the State monad ? I know of STArray in the ST monad and IOArray in the IO monad

Comment: @is7s I ment ST with state. Sorry for being inprecise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As svenningsson suggests,  [priority search queue](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/PSQueue/1.1/doc/html/Data-PSQueue.html) is well suited for both Kruskal's and Prim's (atleast the author proclaims it in his [paper](http://portal.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=507650&type=pdf&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=74270503&CFTOKEN=40353710).) The problem with Kruskal is that it requires that you have an O(log n) [union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-find). A union-find datastructure with a purely functional interface is described [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1292541), but it uses mutable state internally, and a purely functional implementation might be impossible and in fact, there are several problems where an efficient purely functional solution is not known, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990464/efficiency-of-purely-functional-programming) related SO question.

A non-pure alterenative is to implement union-find algorithm in the ST monad. A search on Hackage finds that the [equivalence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/equivalence) package suits our needs. Following is an implementation of Kruskal using Data.Equivalence.Monad from the [equivalence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/equivalence) package:

```
import Data.Equivalence.Monad
import Data.Graph as G
import Data.List(sortBy)
import Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad(filterM)
import Data.Ord(comparing)

run = runEquivM (const ()) (const $ const ())

kruskal weight graph = run $
 filterM go (sortBy (comparing weight) theEdges)
     where
      theEdges = G.edges graph
      go (u,v) = do 
        eq <- equivalent u v
        if eq then return False else
         equate u v >> return True
```

It can be used like this:

```
fromL xs = fromJust . flip M.lookup (M.fromList xs)

testWeights = fromL [((1,2),1),((2,3),4),((3,4),5),((1,4),30),((1,3),4)]
testGraph = G.buildG  (1,4) [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4),(1,3)]
test = kruskal testWeights testGraph
```

and running test gives:

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(3,4)]
```

It should be noted that the running time is dependent on weights running in O(1) time, however `fromL` creates a weight function running in O(log(n)) time, this can be improved to O(1) time by using arrays or just keeping track of the weight in the input list, but it's not really part of the algorithm.

Comment: It seems there exists an efficient persistent implementation: www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/puf-wml07.ps

Comment: @Landei, so it seems, I will update my answer once I have done some research about it.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a crude Kruskal implementation.

```
import Data.List(sort)
import Data.Set (Set, member, fromList, insert, union)

data Edge a = Edge a a Double deriving Show

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Edge a) where
  Edge x1 y1 z1 == Edge x2 y2 z2 = x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && z1 == z2

instance Eq a => Ord (Edge a) where
  (Edge _ _ x) `compare` (Edge _ _ y) = x `compare` y

kruskal :: Ord a => [Edge a] -> [Edge a]
kruskal = fst . foldl mst ([],[]) . sort

mst :: Ord a => ([Edge a],[Set a]) -> Edge a -> ([Edge a],[Set a])
mst (es, sets) e@(Edge p q _) = step $ extract sets where
   step (rest, Nothing, Nothing) = (e : es, fromList [p,q] : rest)
   step (rest, Just ps, Nothing) = (e : es, q `insert` ps : rest)
   step (rest, Nothing, Just qs) = (e : es, p `insert` qs : rest)
   step (rest, Just ps, Just qs) | ps == qs = (es, sets) --circle
                                 | otherwise = (e : es, ps `union` qs : rest)
   extract = foldr f ([], Nothing, Nothing) where
       f s (list, setp, setq) =
            let list' = if member p s || member q s then list else s:list
                setp' = if member p s then Just s else setp
                setq' = if member q s then Just s else setq
            in (list', setp', setq')
```

The first step is sorting the edges, which is O(n log n). The problem is to find a faster lookup for the vertex sets in the extract function. I couldn't find a faster solution for this, maybe someone has an idea...

[Update]

For a Scala implementation I used a map-like data-structure for (hopefully) better performance, but unfortunately it uses mutable sets, and I have no clue how to translate this into Haskell. The code is in my blog (sorry, description is in German): http://dgronau.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/nochmal-kruskal/

Answer (score 3):

I think a priority search queue is what you're looking for. It can be implemented optimally in a functional language as demonstrated by Ralf Hinze in [a paper](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/publications/publication1150-abstract.html). It seems like the paper is only available via acm's library at a cost.

Comment: The article is available here: (http://portal.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=507650&type=pdf&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=74270503&CFTOKEN=40353710