# Detect cycle in undirected graph in Ocaml

Tags: graph, tree, ocaml, cycle

Does someone has idea how to detect if there is a cycle in undirected graph in OCaml?

Here's the type I'm using for graph:

```
type 'a graph = { 
  nodes : 'a list; 
  edges : ('a * 'a * int) list 
}
```

And for example, I would like to check if this graph contains cycles:

```
let graph = { 
  nodes = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'j';]; 
  edges = [
    ('c', 'j', 9); ('d', 'e', 8); ('a', 'b', 8); 
    ('b', 'c', 7); ('f', 'g', 6); ('b', 'h', 4); 
    ('a', 'd', 4); ('g', 'h', 2); ('b', 'f', 2); 
    ('e', 'g', 1)
  ]
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use a graph traversal algorithm on a graph with cycle? What experiment did you try? Where did you get stuck? Do you have some starting code that fails to work? It would be much more helpful if you spent a little more time to craft your question.

Comment: I'm implementing Kruskal's algorithm for minimum spanning trees and I'm stuck with detecting if there is a cycle in edges that I already extracted. So, I'm having a graph like I've written in the example and I'm iterating over it taking each time the edge with minimal weight, but I can't take an edge that makes cycle. So, now I'm stuck with it because I don't know how to detect if there is a cycle.

Comment: If you keep track of which nodes you've seen so far, you can detect that you're in a cycle just by checking whether the current node is in the set of seen nodes.

Comment: I can't keep track on them, or at least I don't know how, because I'm taking only edges into consideration. So in my opinion I should every time do some algorithm (DST or similar) to check if there is a path that leads to inital node, but I don't how I would do that either. I'm new in OCaml.
I was also reading that Kruskal's algorithm should contain union-find algorithm, but I don't know how to implement it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290163/how-can-i-write-a-mst-algorithm-prim-or-kruskal-in-haskell

Comment: That's a already better question, you should edit your initial question to add this kind of minimal information. And yes, union-help can be used to detect if two vertices belong to the same connected components of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to detect cycle by using union-find data structure.

A structure to represent a subset for union-find:

```
let create n =
    {parent = Array.init n (fun i -> i);
     rank = Array.init n (fun i -> 0)}
```

A utility function to find set of an element. It uses path compression technique:

```
let rec find uf i =
  let pi = uf.parent.(i) in
  if pi == i then
     i
  else begin
     let ci = find uf pi in
     uf.parent.(i) <- ci;
     ci
  end
```

A function that does union of two sets of x and y. It uses union by rank:

```
let union ({ parent = p; rank = r } as uf) x y =
    let cx = find uf x in
    let cy = find uf y in
    if cx == cy then raise (Failure "Cycle detected") else  begin
       if r.(cx) > r.(cy) then
          p.(cy) <- cx
       else if r.(cx) < r.(cy) then
          p.(cx) <- cy
       else begin
          r.(cx) <- r.(cx) + 1;
          p.(cy) <- cx
       end
    end
```

I created function for checking if there is a cycle.

```
let thereIsCycle c1 c2 g subset =
  let isCycle = try Some (union subset (findIndex c1 g.nodes) (findIndex c2 g.nodes)) with _ -> None in
      match isCycle with
     | Some isCycle -> false
     | None -> true

let rec findIndex x lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> raise (Failure "Not Found")
    | h :: t -> if x = h then 0 else 1 + findIndex x t
```

Answer (score 0):

In both directed and undirected graphs, the presence of a cycle is detected using [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Roughly, you traverse a graph and if a walk contains repetitive nodes, then there is a cycle.

Commonly, an additional data structure is employed for labeling already visited nodes. For example, we can employ a set data structure (using vanilla OCaml),

```
module Nodes = Set.Make(struct 
                 type t = int
                 let compare = compare
               end)

let dfs {edges} f x = 
 let rec loop visited x = function
   | [] -> x 
   | (src,dst,data) :: rest -> 
     let x = f src data in
     let visited = Nodes.add src visited in
     if Nodes.mem dst visited 
     then loop visited x rest
     else ... in
  loop Nodes.empty x edges
```

You can also use an imperative hash table instead of a pure functional set. There is also an algorithm, called [Iterative Deepening DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search%5C), that can traverse cyclic graphs without labeling all visited nodes, which is useful when your graph is huge (and won't fit into the memory).

Unless you're doing this for an exercise, I would suggest you using some existing Graph library in OCaml, e.g., [OCamlgraph](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ocamlgraph/) ([docs](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/)) or [Graphlib](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/graphlib/) ([docs](http://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/odoc/graphlib/Graphlib/Std/index.html)).

Comment: Suggestion: `module Node = Set.Make (Int)`

Comment: The older versions of the OCaml standard library lack module Int or when it is present it lacks type t or compare functions, so this is not always working.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to avoid visiting the same edge twice by removing it from the list of available edges; assuming order does not matter in among edges, you can remove an edge as follows:

```
let edges_remove_edge edges edge =
  let (src, dst, _) = edge in
  let rec iter edges res = match edges with
    | [] -> res
    | ((s, d, _) as e)::edges ->
       if (s = src && d = dst) then
         res @ edges
       else
         iter edges (e::res)
  in iter edges []
```

Removing an edge from a graph is then done by building a new graph that shares data with the previous graph, but with a modified list of edges:

```
let graph_remove_edge graph edge =
  { nodes = graph.nodes;
    edges = edges_remove_edge graph.edges edge }
```

You can then transform the graph along the recursive calls of your graph traversal; the example does nothing interesting here, it is just to demonstrate the structure:

```
let choose_edge graph = match graph.edges with
  | [] -> None
  | e::_ -> Some e;;

let rec visit graph = match (choose_edge graph) with
  | None -> graph
  | Some e -> visit (graph_remove_edge graph e);;

# visit graph;;
- : char graph =
{nodes = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'j']; edges = []}
```

Or, you keep track of the current graph with a ref:

```
let visit2 graph =
  let g = ref graph in
  let rec v () = match (choose_edge !g) with
  | None -> ()
  | Some e -> begin g := graph_remove_edge !g e; v () end
  in v(); !g
```