# What container really mimics std::vector in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell

#### The problem

I'm looking for a container that is used to save partial results of `n - 1` problems in order to calculate the `n`th one. This means that the size of the container, at the end, will always be `n`.

Each element, `i`, of the container depends on at least 2 and up to 4 previous results.

The container have to provide:

- constant time insertions at either beginning or end (one of the two, not necessarily both)
- constant time indexing in the middle

or alternatively (given a `O(n)` initialization):

- constant time single element edits
- constant time indexing in the middle

#### What is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and why is it relevant

For those of you who don't know C++, `std::vector` is a dynamically sized array. It is a perfect fit for this problem because it is able to:

- reserve space at construction
- offer constant time indexing in the middle
- offer constant time insertion at the end (with a reserved space)

Therefore this problem is solvable in `O(n)` complexity, in C++.

#### Why `Data.Vector` is not `std::vector`

`Data.Vector`, together with `Data.Array`, provide similar functionality to `std::vector`, but not quite the same. Both, of course, offer constant time indexing in the middle, but they offer neither constant time modification (`(//)` for example is at least `O(n)`) nor constant time insertion at either beginning of end.

#### Conclusion

What container really mimics `std::vector` in Haskell? Alternatively, what is my best shot?

Comment: "constant time modification" Non-destructive modification in O(1)... basically, forget about it. If you want destructive modification, try `Data.Vector.Mutable`.

Comment: You should read this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Dynamic_programming_example for a functional solution to your problem that does not require modifiable data structures.

Comment: I think this should be reopened.  The linked answer is not satisfactory and vaguely suggests a non-existent solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/27zap8/what_container_really_mimics_stdvector_in_haskell/ci60pa4) comes the suggestion to use [`Data.Vector.constructN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:constructN):

> O(n) Construct a vector with n elements by repeatedly applying the generator function to the already constructed part of the vector.
>
> ```
>  constructN 3 f = let a = f <> ; b = f <a> ; c = f <a,b> in f <a,b,c>
> ```

For example:

```
λ import qualified Data.Vector as V
λ V.constructN 10 V.length
fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
λ V.constructN 10 $ (1+) . V.sum
fromList [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
λ V.constructN 10 $ \v -> let n = V.length v in if n <= 1 then 1 else (v V.! (n - 1)) + (v V.! (n - 2))
fromList [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

This certainly seems to qualify to solve the problem as you've described it above.

Answer (score 9):

The first data structures that come to my mind are either Maps from `Data.Map` or Sequences from `Data.Sequence`.

## Update

### [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html)

Sequences are persistent data structures that allow most operations efficient, while allowing only finite sequences. Their implementation is based on [finger-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger-tree), if you are interested. But which qualities does it have?

- **O(1)** calculation of the length
- **O(1)** insert at front/back with the operators `<|` and `|>` respectively.
- **O(n)** creation from a list with `fromlist`
- **O(log(min(n1,n2)))** concatenation for sequences of length n1 and n2.
- **O(log(min(i,n-i)))** indexing for an element at position `i` in a sequence of length n.

Furthermore this structure supports a lot of the known and handy functions you'd expect from a list-like structure: `replicate`, `zip`, `null`, `scan`s, `sort`, `take`, `drop`, `splitAt` and many more. Due to these similarities you have to do either qualified import or hide the functions in `Prelude`, that have the same name.

### `Data.Map`

`Maps` are the standard workhorse for realizing a correspondence between "things", what you might call a Hashmap or associave array in other programming languages are called Maps in Haskell; other than in say Python `Maps` are pure - so an update gives you back a new Map and does not modify the original instance.

Maps come in two flavors - [strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) and [lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html).

Quoting from the Documentation

#### Strict

> API of this module is strict in both the keys and the values.

#### Lazy

> API of this module is strict in the keys, but lazy in the values.

So you need to choose what fits best for your application. You can try both versions and benchmark with [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Instead of listing the features of `Data.Map` I want to pass on to

### [`Data.IntMap.Strict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html)

Which can leverage the fact that the keys are integers to squeeze out a better performance
Quoting from the documentation we first note:

> Many operations have a worst-case complexity of O(min(n,W)). This means that the operation can become linear in the number of elements with a maximum of W -- the number of bits in an Int (32 or 64).

So what are the characteristics for `IntMaps`

- **O(min(n,W))** for (unsafe) indexing `(!)`, unsafe in the sense that you will get an error if the key/index does not exist. This is the same behavior as `Data.Sequence`.
- **O(n)** calculation of `size`
- **O(min(n,W))** for safe indexing `lookup`, which returns a `Nothing` if the key is not found and `Just a` otherwise.
- **O(min(n,W))** for `insert`, `delete`, `adjust` and `update`

So you see that this structure is less efficient than `Sequences`, but provide a bit more safety and a big benefit if you actually don't need all entries, such the representation of a sparse graph, where the nodes are integers.

For completeness I'd like to mention a package called [`persistent-vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-vector), which implements clojure-style vectors, but seems to be abandoned as the last upload is from (2012).

### Conclusion

So for your use case I'd strongly recommend `Data.Sequence` or [`Data.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.5), unfortunately I don't have any experience with the latter, so you need to try it for yourself. From the stuff I know it provides a powerful thing called stream fusion, that optimizes to execute multiple functions in one tight "loop" instead of running a loop for each function. A tutorial for `Vector` can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have time right now - will elaborate some more if necessary in the evening (gmt+1)

Comment: thanks for the reminder, work got the best of me so I had no head for writing an answer.

Answer (score 3):

When looking for functional containers with particular asymptotic run times, I always pull out [Edison](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonCore).

Note that there's a result that in a strict language with immutable data structures, there's always a logarithmic slowdown to implementing mutable data structure on top of them.  It's an open problem whether the limited mutation hidden behind laziness can avoid that slowdown.  There also the issue of persistent vs. transient...

Okasaki is still a good read for background, but finger trees or something more complex like an RRB-tree should be available "off-the-shelf" and solve your problem.

Comment: I've heard this logarithm slow down referred to before. Does it have a name, or anything more Googlable?

Comment: @ocharles I think this has all the right references, Wikipedia does not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1990580/2008899

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a container that is used to save partial results of n - 1 problems in order to calculate the nth one.
>
> Each element, i, of the container depends on at least 2 and up to 4 previous results.

Lets consider a very small program. that calculates fibonacci numbers.

```hs
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1 
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

This is great for small N, but horrible for n > 10. At this point, you stumble across this gem:

```hs
fib n = fibs !! n where fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

You may be tempted to exclaim that this is dark magic (infinite, self referential list building and zipping? wth!) but it is really a great example of tying the knot, and using lazyness to ensure that values are calcuated as-needed.

Similarly, we can use an array to tie the knot too.

```hs
import Data.Array

fib n = arr ! 10
  where arr :: Arr Int Int
        arr = listArray (1,n) (map fib' [1..n])
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' 2 = 1
        fib' n = arr!(n-1) + arr!(n-2)
```

Each element of the array is a thunk that uses other elements of the array to calculate it's value. In this way, we can build a single array, never having to perform concatenation, and call out values from the array at will, only paying for the calculation up to that point.

The beauty of this method is that you don't only have to look behind you, you can look in front of you as well.