# Is it possible to create a universal intermediate programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

What I mean is, is there a language or could one be designed, such that all high level programming languages could be compiled into this intermediate language?

This is excluding machine languages.

Comment: This isn't clear.  And probably opinion-based, since there is no objective definition of "high-level".  Does LLVM count, for example?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I made that clear, it can't be machine language.

Comment: LLVM isn't a machine language, in the sense that there is no machine that natively runs it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's the same sense that all languages which are not machine languages are not machine languages. So yes, LLVM would be a candidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every general-purpose language that is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) is a universal programming language.

Two languages (or machines) are considered to be Turing-equivalent if any program for one can be compiled into a program for the other. A language is Turing-complete if it is Turing-equivalent to a Turing machine.

There were several early efforts to formalize the notion of a computation; a Turing machine was one, the lambda calculus another, and the class of general recursive functions a third. Alonzo Church and Alan Turing proved that all three of these formalizations were Turing-equivalent; any program for a Turing machine could be compiled to the lambda calculus, and vice versa, as could any general recursive function be implemented by either the lambda calculus or a Turing machine, and again vice versa.

The [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) hypothesizes that any computation that can be expressed in any formal system can be converted into a program that can run on a Turing machine; or equivalently, can be expressed in the untyped lambda calculus, or is general recursive, based on the equivalence described above.

It is merely a hypothesis and cannot be formally proven, as there is no way to formally characterize the class of computations that are subject to it (without circular reasoning by defining them as the class of computations that can be performed by a Turing machine), but there has never been any proposed model of computation that is not possible to compute with a Turing machine.

Because you can write a simulator of a Turing machine (or implementation of lambda calculus) in almost any general purpose language, and likewise those languages can be compiled to a program running on a Turing machine, pretty much all general purpose languages are Turing complete.

There are, however, some languages which are not Turing complete; regular expressions are an example. They can be simulated by a Turing machine, but they cannot in turn simulate a Turing machine.

Note that none of this addresses efficiency or access to host system resources; merely that the same computation can be expressed, and that it will eventually provide the same answer. There are some languages that are Turing complete in which there are some problems that [cannot be computed at the same asymptotic efficiency as in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990464/efficiency-of-purely-functional-programming/1990580#1990580). And some languages provide access to external resources like the filesystem, I/O, networking, etc, while others which just allow computation in memory, but in any language that is Turing complete it would be possible to add an API or method of manipulating memory that allows it to access those external resources, so lack of access to system resources isn't a fundamental limitation, just a limitation of implementation.

As a more practical matter, there are several languages that have been designed to be portable, intermediate languages that are targets of compilation. The [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/) is one commonly used example, [C--](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/c--/index.html) is another. Also, any bytecode for a language runtime acts this way, the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is a compilation target for many languages, the [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) is another. Finally, many languages compile to C, as C compilers are widely available and the code is more portable than machine code.

And more recently, with the advent of the web and JavaScript being a language that is available in every web browser, JavaScript has become a popular target for compilation, both for languages that were designed to compile down to JavaScript like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), but also existing languages that were originally design to compile to machine code, via projects like [Emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/). Recognizing this usage, there has been effort to specify a subset of JavaScript, with more strict rules, known as [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/), that makes a better target for compilation, while still allowing the same code to work backwards-compatibly with regular JavaScript engines that don't know anything about asm.js.

Comment: So you're saying all Turing-complete languages can be compiled into each other?

Comment: @KthProg: Any Turing-equivalent system can simulate any other Turing-equivalent system.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth All of a sudden you know the answer, too. Even though you likely downvoted and tried to close this question as opinion-based.

Comment: @KthProg: I already knew the answer.  I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close (because it was unclear what distinction you were trying to draw with machine languages...)  But given that you seem to be saying that this is an acceptable answer to your question, happy to count that as a clarified question, so will withdraw the close-vote!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Okay thanks! Anyways, if one can simulate the other, then It seems like compiling is possible.

Comment: @sepp2k Well, you wouldn't turn a sphere inside out, but that also is rigorously possible in mathematics lol.

Comment: @KthProg I'm not sure how that addresses my question. I'd appreciate it if you could be more clear.

Comment: @KthProg I've expanded my answer to provide some more information, though you can also follow the links to Wikipedia to read more.

Comment: @KthProg Expanded my answer a little more to also include examples of languages that are frequently used as compilation targets; while any language could be used as such in theory, there are several that are designed for the purpose, and several more that are used as compilation targets due to their ubiquity (like C and JavaScript).